# Creating a tar with a absolute path

Tags: ssh, tar, mv

```
tar -cf /Users/Files/myfile.tar /Users/Files/
```

I am basically trying to create a tar containing the contents of User/Files and create it in the folder of the contents.

I can only execute this process in one line, so I cannot cd before.

Answer (score 1):

Since this nine year old just popped up as modified, I thought I would chime in. You can put the tar file into the directory being archived with an exclusion.

```
tar -cf /Users/Files/myfile.tar --exclude=myfile.tar /Users/Files/
```

Creates the archive on the directory but explicitly does not try to tar up the new file being created.

The answer by [@yco](https://superuser.com/a/628088/912264) does assume that you have sufficient disk space to create the archive in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

`tar -cf myfile.tar /Users/Files/ && mv myfile.tar /Users/Files/`
One line right? :D

You are archiving a folder and writing in it at the same time. That's really wrong and thankfully it does not work.

Since you are using ssh to pass this command you have most likely use something like this:

```
ssh <user>@<host> -- tar -cf myfile.tar /Users/Files/ && mv myfile.tar /Users/Files/
```

But in this example the `&&` works between `ssh` and `mv` and not `tar` and `mv`.
Use this instead:

```
ssh <user>@<host> -- "tar -cf myfile.tar /Users/Files/ && mv myfile.tar /Users/Files/"
```

By the way, The `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names` warning you may see is only a warning, not an error due to an absolute path.

Comment: The file doesn'¨t seem to be moved when executing a ls right aftr

Comment: it works fine on my debian :/ what system are you under?
You can replace `&&` by `;` but both are supposed to work.
Why is you question tagged under ssh btw?

Comment: since im using ssh :P

Comment: Then tell it in your question body!
I will edit my answer then

Comment: I think I found the reason it didn't work, it was because of file permissions...

Comment: ok :)
Next time try to be more explicit about your issue, like return code, commands you passed etc.